# @PathParam getting null value

Tags: java, web-services, rest

Thank you for your help even if you just read it.

Problem: return value is null why?
Have checked many forums and everything seems to be fine, but isn't.

```
package pack.bb;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("path")
public class test {
    @GET
    @Path("{sorted}")
    public String getsortedContactList(@PathParam("list") String list) //throws SQLException
    {
        System.out.println("GET list: " + list);
        return "get " + list;
    }
}
```

I am using this using localHost 8080

```
"localHost:8080/testCap/api/path/aaaa"
```

This is web.xml file. I think it is correct because I was using it in other projects

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Factorial_RESTapp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>pack.bb</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

After running I get this result in console:

GET list: null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
@Path("/{list}")
public String getsortedContactList(@PathParam("list") String list)
```

Instead of `{sorted}`. The first @Path identifies the section in the url and @PathParam then tells which variable is used for it, so they have to match. The last one, variable name, can be anything.

Comment: this was exactly my problem. It works right now. Thank you. Could you please tell me why all of them have to be list?

Comment: they don't all have to be. The first `@Path` identifies the section in the url and `@PathParam` then tells which variable is used for it, so they have to match. The last one, variable name, can be anything.